# How do I stop cd command from printing absolute path everytime?

Tags: command-line, bash, cd-command

I edited my .bashrc to add more directories to $CDPATH. It looks like this:

```
export CDPATH=".:~:~/LEI/2_ano/2_smt:~/LEI/2_ano/1_smt"
```

But now every time I use the cd command, it prints the absolute path. For example, if I do `cd ~/Downloads`, the result is

```
/home/user_name/Downloads
User_prompt:~/Downloads$
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can stop it from printing, since that's [the documented behavior](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-cd):

> If a non-empty directory name from `CDPATH` is used, or if ‘`-`’ is
> the first argument, and the directory change is successful, the
> absolute pathname of the new working directory is written to the
> standard output.

However you could overload `cd` with a shell function that redirects standard output:

```
cd ()
{
    command cd "$@" > /dev/null
}
```

Comment: I wrote a custom `cd` function for someone before: [How do I prevent 'cd' command from going to home directory?[](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086161/how-do-i-prevent-cd-command-from-going-to-home-directory/1086196#1086196) and it was not well received. Some frown on writing functions that override built ins.

Comment: Perhaps more "elegant": `alias cd='>/dev/null cd'`

Comment: @vanadium this solved the problem. You may write a full answer if you will!

Comment: @steeldriver, perhaps you care adding this to your answer? Your approach works equally well, but a solution where you just add one more alias is more elegant and straightforward.

Comment: command cd ${1+"$@"} -- without that wrapper, the behavior changes.